# ajax "busy" indicator but only for longer requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to specify time after which I can show busy indicator?

My code for busy indicator is quite simple:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {
    beforeSend:function ()
    {
        jQuery( "#busy-indicator" ).show();
    }, complete:function ()
    {
        jQuery( "#busy-indicator" ).hide();
    }
} );
```

But often Ajax request is faster then appearing indicator, therefore I'd like to show it for request which take lets say at least 1 second, is it possible? Or Do you have idea how to do it?

Comment: in the beforeSend callback launch a timeout that will show your loader after a while and in the complete callback cancel the timeout and hide the loader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
var timeout; 
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {
    beforeSend:function ()
    {
        if (timeout) { clearTimeout(timeout); }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery( "#busy-indicator" ).show(); 
        }, 1000);
    }, 
    complete:function ()
    {
        if (timeout) { clearTimeout(timeout); } 
        jQuery( "#busy-indicator" ).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: One thing after some testing that I'd add to your code: `if (timeout) { clearTimeout(timeout); } ` also at the beginning of beforeSend, 2 consecutive ajax request messed a little timeout :)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {
    beforeSend:function ()
    {
        $( "#busy-indicator" ).stop(1,0).hide().delay(1000).show();
    }, 
    complete:function ()
    {
        $( "#busy-indicator" ).stop(1,0).hide();
    }
});
```

Doesn't this also work?

Comment: This is a more jqueryish way to do this :). Could you explain the `.stop(1,0)` ?

Comment: Well .stop(1,0) tells jQuery to clear the animation queue for this element so that the animation will not run multiple times (with 1 second delay between animations) if the ajax function is called multiple times. So before an ajax call we make sure that no other animation from a previous call is running, then we hide the indicator if it's visible then we display it with one second delay.